# what is fragment activity in android studio?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm new to android. i have huge confusion on handling fragments. i'll be pleased if anyone suggest me to know about handling fragments in android? It'll be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Comment: Please don't spam keywords. For example, the [android-studio] tag should only be used for questions about the tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `fragments` to!

What I do is that I have a `FrameLayout` inside the `activity_main.xml` and then I replace the `Framelayout` with the `fragment` I want.

If you search here in **StackOverflow** there's so much information about it.